# Simulating calls in Android Emulator

Tags: android

Simulating calls in Emulator
 My emulator doesn't have a phone symbol/ application, is there anyway I can add that to the hardware skin or home screen? Also, I am trying to simulate incoming calls in the Android emulator but when I try the following commands, it doesn't seem to work:

In windows powershell:

Command 1 : telnet

Command 2 : open localhost 5554

Command 3 : gsm call 012345678

I don't think calls are implemented in genymotion. Please correct me if I am wrong.

When I go to eclipse -> Windows -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Emulator call and try to call thru there, still no sign on the emulator of an incoming call. Not sure why no calls are coming into the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using different Android SDK version - Version 8 and Emulator Android 2.2 after installing it in my Android SDK Manager.